# github pushing local copy to remote

Tags: github

I created a branch locally and remotely. To synchronize the changes between local and master, I pulled the changes from master, rebased onto master and resolve the conflicts.

```
Changes on master

A -- B

Changes on local branch

C -- D -- E -- F

Local branch after rebase

A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
```

However, when I subsequently tried to push the local branch to the remote branch. It prompts me to resolve conflicts again. After resolving the conflict, the history of commits is showing up

```
C -- D -- E -- F -- A -- B -- C -- D --E -- F
```

was expecting same as local branch after rebase as per below

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
```

how to achieve the above?

Comment: What happens when your try to push?

Comment: push would give conflicts and after resolving those conflicts it becomes C -- D -- E  -- F -- A -- B --C -- D -- E -- F

Comment: push cannot give conflicts, you can only get an error that you’re not allowed to push for some reason. Post the error please.

Comment: push of current branch was rejected. Remote changes need to be merged before pushing.

Comment: *edit* Did you finish your rebase before trying to push?

Comment: yup I did.. the rebase was successful and all conflicts were resolved. I think the reason could be because the remote branch is Z - C - D - E - F and now the local branch instead of being Z - C - D - E -F .. becomes Z - A - B - C - D - E - F.. so it doesn't recognize

Comment: That means you rebased the remote changes on top of your local changes and not the other way around (which you’re supposed to). That also means your `remote/test` is Z→C→D→E→F (which is contrary to your question) and your `test` is Z→A→B→C*→D*→E*→F*. If you are happy with your local branch as is (meaning in contains everything you want it to contain in the right order and nothing more) you can safely push `--force-with-lease`.

Comment: i see ... so if it was Z - C - D - E - F - A - B instead it would be ok

Comment: Please add asterisks to changed commits, it will make understanding it much easier. And yes, because then both your local and your remote branch would contain Z to F (the original and not a rebased version) and you’d put your (rebased) A* and B* commits on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes on master
A -- B
Local branch after rebase
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F

After `rebase` operation, local branch is already differed from remote.

Now out target is: remote branch
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F

I have a "dangerous" advice:
 1. **Make sure you have backup of your code.**
 2. rebase your local branch like this(our target):
 A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
 3. `git push --force` to your remote branch. Then your remote branch will be like your local branch.

The `--force` is very **DANGEROUS**. Be careful.

Hope it works :)

Comment: There shouldn’t be a need to force push anything here. Also never `--force` but `--force-with-lease`.

Comment: @Darklighter  You are right. This is not a good solution. Sometimes I do this operation on my own project. But we don't allow this in team work.

Comment: so it is better to leave it as C -- D -- E -- F -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F rather than force pushing?

Comment: When I want to hide something or destroy remote branch on my own project, I woundl force push. If  not for some special reasons I suggest you to leave it rather than force pushing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t have conflicts pushing if the remote didn’t change in the meantime.

If it did you need to rebase again:

- I would revert your first rebase via a reset of your local branch to your F commit.
- pull with rebase
- push

Why does your local branch start with C and your remote branch with A, do they not have a common ancestor?
And also, after rebase your commits are different, I would mark them with an asterisk or something for distinguishment.

Comment: local branch is rebased on to master so it starts from A but remote branch is stil C -> D -> E -> F... want to configure it so that remote is also rebased

Comment: How does your remote branch start with a different commit than your local branch? Also `master` _is_ your local branch `origin/master` is the remote branch.

Comment: when i pulled master and created a local branch the last commit on both branches is Z, then you have Z on master and Z on local branch.. subsequently master becomes Z -> A -> B and local branch Z -> C -> D -> E -> F. pushing the local branch to remote after each commit, remote branch becomes Z -> C -> D -> E -> F as well. Now rebase is done on local which makes it Z -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F but I can't get remote branch to be the same by pushing

Comment: If `origin/master` is Z→A→B and rebased `master` is Z→A→B→C*→D*→E*→F* you are able to push. So it seems that that’s not the case.

Comment: ok to be clearer.. the local branch is another branch name branched off from master (when last commit is Z), called test. and this test branch is pushed to remote when it is Z - C - D - E - F so now trying to push local/test to origin/test but the push is rejected